# Datepicker android junit

Tags: android, datepicker, junit3

I am new to  Android Junit, i have been trying to write test case to a sample application that displays a datepicker on click of button and display it in the textview.
I am able to write unit  test case to check if the button is getting clicked and datepicker is opening, but on opening of the datepicker how do i change the date in datepicker to a particular date and cross check it with the result in textview using assert.
I have used 
**TouchUtils.clickView(this, mdate);** to click , mdate is the name of the button in testfile refering to the button in main java file.

Please guide me with this, i am not sure if my understanding is correct

Comment: Will the change in the date in the datepicker occur when the user clicks on a particular date in the datepicker?

Comment: yes in the application it does, and the new date gets displayed in textview. but in the test file, on click of button datepicker opens and test case ends because of which it closes.

Comment: Ok, as as far as i understand, what you want to do is click on the date picker, change the date and see if the date coming on a text view si coming correctly as per the changed date . Is that right ?

Comment: yes,i need to write test case to do that. and date picker is invoked on click of the button only

Comment: Ok i understand your problem now. I am running a simulation based on it. Will get back to you, if i can find an answer to the same.